# What should the object type be to have a chained call?

Tags: c++, pointers, call, chained

Can someone please tell me what the difference is between the two codes for `class Point` and `class Dog`? `Dog` compiles without any error. `Point` throws an error if the `point` object is from the stack and not called via a pointer. Why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

class Dog{
    public : 
    
        Dog() = default;
        Dog(std::string_view name_param, std::string_view breed_param, int  age_param){
            name = name_param;
            breed = breed_param;
            p_age = new int;
            *p_age = age_param;
    
        }
        void print_info(){
            std::cout << "Dog (" << this << ") : [ name : " << name 
                << " breed : " << breed << " age : " << *p_age << "]" << std::endl;
        }

        //Setters
        //Chained calls using pointers
        
        Dog* set_dog_name(std::string_view name){
            //name = name; // This does nothing
            this->name = name;
            return this;
        }

        Dog* set_dog_breed(std::string_view breed){
            this->breed = breed;
            return this;
        }

        Dog* set_dog_age(int age){
            *(this->p_age) = age;
            return this;
        }
        

    private : 
        std::string name;
        std::string breed;
        int * p_age{nullptr};
};


int main(){

    Dog dog1("Fluffy","Shepherd",2); //Constructor
    dog1.print_info();

    //Chained calls using pointers
    dog1.set_dog_name("Pumba")->set_dog_breed("Wire Fox Terrier")->set_dog_age(4);

    dog1.print_info();

    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
   //Destructor
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

class Point{
    public : 
    
    Point() = default;
    Point(double x, double y){
        m_x = x; 
        m_y = y;
    }
    
    void print_point(){
        std::cout << "Point[x : " << m_x << ", y : " << m_y << "]" ;
    }

    Point* set_x(double m_x){
        this->m_x = m_x;
        return this;
    }

    Point* set_y(double m_y){
        this->m_y = m_y;
        return this;
    }

    //member variables
    private : 
        double m_x{1};
        double m_y{1};
};

int main(){
    
    Point p1(1.1, 2.2);
    //Point* p_ptr {&p1}; 
    p1.print_point();
    p1->set_x(21.2)->set_y(4.2); //error.error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Point’                                      
    p1.print_point();            //works only if p_ptr->set_x(21.2)->set_y(4.2);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the `Dog` class is working with a regular object, but the `Point` class needs a pointer.

Comment: `dog1.set_dog_name` is using `.`, but `p1->set_x` is using `->`, which is tripping the error.  Also, in my opinion, the setters are returning a pointer — but they ought to return a reference, via `return *this;` instead.  (But actually, I think setters should return `void`, instead of encouraging this "fluent style" of chained methods programming.)

Comment: I would argue that both are bad implementations of this pattern. Being required to use a pointer, or mixing `.` and `->` is not great.

Comment: I recommend you return a reference instead. Like e.g. `Dog& set_dog_breed(std::string_view breed){ /* ... */ return *this; }`. Makes the syntax a little nicer and consistent IMO: `dog1.set_dog_name("Pumba").set_dog_breed("Wire Fox Terrier").set_dog_age(4);`

Answer (score 4):

`p1` is an object, not a pointer to an object. Therefore, you need to use the dot operator to access its member variables and member functions. You can't use the arrow operator on an object without it being a pointer, or having overloaded the arrow operator.

If you're going for fluent setters, I suggest you return by reference instead of by pointer, i.e.

```
Dog& set_dog_name(std::string_view name){
    //...
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Eljay mentioned in a comment, you are dereference the initial variable differently in the two examples. The original Dog local variable is used properly with the '.' notation for the first call, and then pointer '->' notation for subsequent calls.
Point uses the pointer '->' notation from the beginning, causing this error.